# Creating query params to set a start and end date/time

Tags: javascript, date, url, parameters

I have been trying to create query parameters to set the start date/time and end date/time to add to Google Calendar from an a tag/link.

My query param is below:

```
`https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text=${Title}&dates=${event.Year}${
  Months.findIndex(e => e === Month) < 10
  ? `0${Months.findIndex(e => e === Month)}`
  : Months.findIndex(e => e === Month)
}${event.Day}${StartTime}T120000Z/${EndYear}${
  Months.findIndex(e => e === EndMonth) < 10 
  ? `0${Months.findIndex(e => e === EndMonth)}`
  : Months.findIndex(e => e === EndMonth)
}${EndDay}${EndTime}T130000Z&sf=true&output=xml`
```

If I remove the Start/End time variables, then it will successfully load the page and display the correct StartDate but the EndDate will not show up. And to be honest, I don't understand the `T130000Z` but it will not work without it.

The link it redirects to (that in part works) is below:

`https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text=Class%20of%202018%20graduation%20celebration&dates=20181212T120000Z/20180426T130000Z&sf=true&output=xml`

Based upon @StephenP's comment, I updated the query to include the time.

I changed `T120000Z` to T${StartTime.split(':').join('')}00Z which successfully added `T010100Z` into the url.

However, despite this, the calendar page is not updating any of the fields except for the Title. Just defaults to today's date.

Comment: The `T` and following is the time representation, which can be in [several formats](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times). `T120000Z` as hhmmss would be 12:00:00, and where the `Z` indicates this is in "[zulu time](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_%28UTC%29)"(UTC). The wikipedia article on [ISO 8601](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date and time format is very informative.

Comment: Mate, this also works without providing the [T<hhmmss><ZONE>] param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the combination i have tried, and was able to set the date:

Changes I have done is (in query):
`sf = true` => `sf = false` 
`dates = <YYYYMMDD>/<YYYYMMDD>` (as START_DATE / END_DATE+1)

**Example:**
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text=Class%20of%202018%20graduation%20celebration&dates=`20180611`/`20180615`&`sf=false`&output=xml

**Output**
[image: Example Output]

Comment: I didn't change `sf=false` to get it to work but I did reverse which item was start and which was end. Once I reversed it, it worked. Would `sf=false` do the same thing?

Comment: Mate, I also don't have clear picture of this `sf` param, and i also dont see this on their doc, but i guess it might `setForword` or something like this.